# How to correctly filter period data in Spark?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am new in `Spark` and need some advice.

I have parquet with a lot of columns. I want to filter the period data for specific mobile numbers.

There are the following input data:

```
val dateFrom = "2018-10-01"
val dateTo = "2018-11-05"
val mobile_numbers = "7778529636,745128598,7777533575"
```

parquet has such structure:

```
| START_DATE          | MOBILE_NUMBER | STATUS | OTHER_COLUMNS
|---------------------|---------------|--------|--------------
| 2018-11-28 20:00:00 | 7778541536    | IN     | ************
| 2018-11-29 00:00:00 | 7786984525    | OUT    | ************
| 2018-11-30 09:00:00 | 7986984525    | IN     | ************
| 2018-12-01 00:30:00 | 7685984425    | OUT    | ************
| 2018-12-02 12:00:00 | 7586984525    | IN     | ************
```

**CODE**:

```
spark.read.parquet("fs://path/file.parquet").filter(???)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that you want to select those rows which fall into the defined date range and have the `MOBILE_NUMBER` column values among the defined numbers list.

First you have to ensure that your data in your Scala code and inside the dataframe are in the same format, so you could compare them correctly. For example:

```
val dateFrom = "2018-10-01 00:00:00"
val dateTo = "2018-11-05 23:59:59"
val mobileNumbers = Vector("7778529636", "745128598", "7777533575")
```

Note that I represent mobile numbers as strings because you might get unexpected results for numbers with zeros in the beginning. The dates are also strings.

Then your filter query could look like this:

```
import spark.implicits._  // for the $"something" syntax

spark.read.parquet("...")
  .filter(
    $"START_DATE".between(dateFrom, dateTo) && $"MOBILE_NUMBER".isin(mobileNumbers: _*)
  )
```

Ideally the dates should be in a format which won't allow ambiguities, e.g. a numerical timestamp, because otherwise it is possible for invalid values like `2018-10-01 56:78:90` to break the comparison, but in most cases this should work, and if it is really necessary, you could write an UDF using the `org.apache.spark.sql.functions.udf` method to ensure that it is completely correct.

Comment: Thank you for detailed information! In fact in my program as input I has such string `"7778529636,745128598,7777533575"` with mobile numbers. I desided to create array like that: `val array_numbers = mobile_numbers.split(",")`. Can I use it instead of `Vector`? What do you think about that?

Comment: @NurzhanNogerbek it will work. The `: _*` _"operator"_ takes any **Seq** _(both Vector and Array are Seqs)_ and pass all its values to a **varargs function** _(which is the case of `isin`)_ - so yes, no problem with it.

Comment: To be completely correct, `Array` is not a `Seq` but it is implicitly convertible to one. And yes, arrays will absolutely work for this purpose too.